# MacOS Ventura how to target ios 10

Tags: ios, xcode

I have to support iOS 10 for my apps.  I recently upgraded to macos Ventura which comes with Xcode 14.  Xcode 14 only supports ios 11+.  I downloaded and installed Xcode 13.4.1 which supports ios 10 but I can't open Xcode 13 directly, I have to open it from the command line; I get this error when I click on Xcode 13 directly: "The version of Xcode installed on this Mac is not compatible with macOS Ventura. Download the latest version for free from the App Store.".
Thank you

Comment: Why are you trying to target iOS 10? That version is almost a decade old, has nearly *no* active users, and was EOL'd by Apple...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that this is possible. Every spring, Apple bumps the requirements for shipping apps to the App Store. Starting today(!), April 25:

> ... iOS, iPadOS, and watchOS apps submitted to the App Store must be built with Xcode 14.1 or later.
>
> [*Apple Developer Announcement*](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=jd9wcyov)

And, because Xcode 14.1 doesn't include support for iOS SDK versions older than iOS 11, I think you're out of luck if you want to ship to the App Store. You could, of course, try setting the minimum deployment target manually:

[image: Screenshot of manual minimum deployment target in Xcode]

*But*, once you do that, Xcode will start throwing up warnings about the use of an unsupported version and incompatibility with the iOS Simulator:

[image: Xcode warning about exceeding the minimum deployment target]

It's possible you could ignore this warning. It sounds like you'd lose iOS Simulator support (so you wouldn't be able to test it, unless you have an iOS 10 device laying around?!?). And you *might* also lose the compile-time checking for deprecated or removed APIs in iOS 10.

---

Even if you're able to get through all those hurdles, uploading to the App Store might cause problems too. I'm not sure if they do checks for this, or prevent you from uploading the app, but it might be worth testing that out before going through all the trouble of supporting iOS 10.

Comment: I missed that announcement, so now it's obvious that apps can't support iOS 10 anymore.  Makes it easier.

Comment: Sorry  good luck with your client! 

Comment: i'm also wondering if apple would reject apps with minimum supported version ios 10 after April 25.